# Regular expression doesn't work as expected: '/=(\w+\s*)+=/'

Tags: php, regex, pcre

This is what I have:

```
<?php

preg_match_all('/=(\w+\s*)+=/', 'aaa =bbb ccc ddd eee= zzz', $match);
print_r($match);
```

It matches only eee:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => =bbb ccc ddd eee=
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => eee
        )

)
```

I need it to match bbb, ccc, ddd, eee, e.g.:

```
...
   [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => bbb
            [1] => ccc
            [2] => ddd
            [3] => eee
        )
...
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: You need to at the very least remove the `+`. And why is it there in the first place?

Comment: [Look at the diagram to see what the regex engine is doing](https://www.debuggex.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
(\w+)(?=[^=]*=[^=]*$)
```

Explaining:

```
(\w+)          # group all words
(?=            # only if right after can be found:
    [^=]*      # regardless of non '=' character
    =          # one '=' character
    [^=]*$     # non '=' character till the end makes sure the first words are eliminated... You can try remove it from regex101 to see what happens.
)
```

[Regex live here.](https://regex101.com/r/fO1lW3/1)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Can you explain it please? I'm kind of lost how the *positive lookahead* will actually look for the first `=`

Comment: Do notice it does not validate for opening `=` ([example](https://regex101.com/r/bQ7rJ4/1)). But that depends on whether the OP wanted validation or not.

Answer (score 1):

Thats is expected behaviour. Group captures are overwritten on repetition.

> 1 group, 1 capture

Instead of trying to get them in 1 match attempt, you should match one token on each attempt. Use `\G` to match [the end of last match](http://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html).

Something like this should work:

```
/(?(?=^)[^=]*+=(?=.*=)|\G\s+)([^\s=]+)/
```

<kbd>[regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yO0wY2/1)</kbd>

---

**Regex break-down**

- `(?(?=^)  ...  |  ...  )` IF on start of string

  - `[^=]*+=` consume everything up to the first `=`
  - `(?=.*=)` and check there's a closing `=` as well
- ELSE

  - `\G\s+` only match if the last match ended here, consuming preceding spaces
- `([^\s=]+)` Match 1 token, captured in group 1.

---

If you're also interested in matching more than 1 set of tokens, you need to match the text in between sets as well:

```
/(?(?=^)[^=]*+=(?=.*=)|\G\s*+(?:=[^=]*+=(?=.*=))?)([^\s=]+)/
```

<kbd>[regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yO0wY2/3)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Your regex starts and ends with an `=`, so the only possible match is:

```
=bbb ccc ddd eee=
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) with [preg_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php), i.e.:

```
$string = "aaa =bbb ccc ddd eee= zzz";
$matches = preg_split('/ /',  preg_replace('/^.*?=|=.*?$/', '', $string));
print_r($matches);
```

---

**OUTPUT:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => bbb
    [1] => ccc
    [2] => ddd
    [3] => eee
)
```

---

**DEMO:**

http://ideone.com/pAmjbk